# Html Minifier Error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi guys i am using Html minifier [ref](http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/a-simple-html-minifier-for-asp-net/2097),but I am getting error in code-`An opening "(" is missing the corresponding closing ").`

Is there any possible way to resolve or anyone have used this,please share your way to use this minifier.

Adding to this - is there any way to **minimize html** in MVC4?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post some html here?
Also provided link is broken,please update it.

Comment: http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/a-simple-html-minifier-for-asp-net/2097

Comment: just post your view over here...

Comment: Are there any JavaScript codes with single line comments start with `//` in your `html` ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're missing a )

Try running the JS through a Linter to detect errors first.

Answer (score 0):

- `Web Essentials` plugin contains a built-in HTML minifier. [More info](http://vswebessentials.com/features/html#minify-html)
- Also you can set it to run automatically: `Tools -> Options -> Web Essentials -> HTML` -> set `Run on build` to true.